# "title" attribute for <html:options> struts tag

Tags: html, apache, struts

In a regular select box you can show the full title on mouseover using "title" attribute in the "option" field.

In Apache Struts, you make the select box with the "html:options" tag.  I don't think this tag supports the "title" attribute.  Is there another way to show the full title of an option on mouseover for the "html:options" struts tag?

Thanks

Comment: The only way I know to do it would be to add the style element and add the on hover in the css.

Comment: If the options in the select box are generated on the fly and not defined in the HTML how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Struts' tag for `<select><option>`.. is `<s:select />`, or `<s:doubleselect />` for double lists. `<s:doubleselect />` doesn't support title at all, you have to modify the Javascript it generates by hand (ddoubleselect.ftl).
For  with the default theme, the file is found in struts2-core-2.1.6.jar under template/simple/.

Answer (score 0):

hard code in html or jsp file is a bad code practice.

if you are writing code in struts 1.x try to store all messages in MessageResources_en.properties

try update your jsp with following (alternatively go for )

```
title="<bean:message key="your_tool_tip"/>
```

and modify MessageResources_en.properties

```
your_tool_tip=toolTIp is a cool idea
```

ps there are solutions available in jquery as well

Answer (score -1):

I'll admit to not being familiar with Apache Struts. If nobody more familiar can find you a better solution then worst case you could do it as a javascript tooltip. It's more effort, but gives you more effective visual control over the presentation.

Comment: onmouseover and onmouseout are invalid tags as well.  good times :D

Is there a diff way to do a js tooltip without using those tags?

Comment: Oh joy. You could give the element a unique id and target that to add the necessary event handlers. A framework like jQuery, Prototype or Mootools would make that easier, though you *can* do it by hand.