# Adding tooltip for html:option struts

Tags: html, struts-1

How to add tooltip for html:options in struts. Basically values we are displaying are too big so we need tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been discussed.
Please refer to this article: ["title" attribute for <html:options> struts tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040088/title-attribute-for-htmloptions-struts-tag)

I am currently working on a workaround way. Once I complete it, I'll post a complete javascript oriented answer :)

Answer (score 0):

hard code in html or jsp file is a bad code practice.

if you are writing code in struts 1.x try to store all messages in MessageResources_en.properties

try update your jsp with following (alternatively go for )

```
title="<bean:message key="your_tool_tip"/>
```

and modify MessageResources_en.properties

```
your_tool_tip=toolTIp is a cool idea
```

ps there are solutions available in jquery as well